# twitter streaming API location

Tags: c#, twitter

I'm trying to implement a twitter stream viewer in C#, my problem doesn't lie within C# itself.

I'm just trying to use the geo-location boxing capability of twitter's streaming API. I'm trying to send a request in this form

```
private string url = @"https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=";
```

and then I append my parameters

```
 for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Count; i++)
        {
            url += keywords[i].ToString() + "%2C";
        }
```

Up until this, the query works fine, it stops working when I add this

```
 url += @"&amp;locations=" + location;
```

Where, location variable has the value

```
-121.75,36.8,-122.75,37.8
```

So I'm ending up with the query looking like this

```
https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter%2Cfacebook%2Ciphone&amp;locations=-121.75,36.8,-122.75,37.8
```

I'm getting a response 406 Not Acceptable, any ideas why?

Comment: `&` used to separete parameters. Don't escape it. Your url should be something like this
`https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter%2Cfacebook%2Ciphone&locations=-121.75,36.8,-122.75,37.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `&amp;` with a standard ampersand.